# Authorization header is missing in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-synapse

I am trying to deploy my ARM template to the QA environment and I have a secret that is being referenced in a keyvault (see below):

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "workspaceName": {
        "value": "myworksapce"
    },
    "QA_password": {
        "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/mytest-qa-group/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/mytest-qa-kv"
            },
            "secretName": "pipeline"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I do the deployment I encounter the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting my secret in the keyvault and use it in the template?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the issue by deploying a keyvault with a secret using Azure portal and used that secret as a password for the VM which will be deployed by using the ARM template.

While creating the keyvault, we should enable the ARM template deployment and also enable the access policies in the Access policy to access the secret from the ARM template and deployed successfully as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Then created a project in Visual Studio and added the above created keyvault secret by clicking on edit parameters--> add the keyvault and save it, then you will see the keyvault has been referenced successfully as shown in below images:

[image]
[image]

To confirm whether our keyvault is successfully linked to our template, you can open the `windowsVMSSparameters.json` file and check the secret name same as created in the keyvault as shown in the below screenshot:

**windowsVMSSparameters.json:**

```
{
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
 "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "parameters": {
   "vmssName": {
     "value": "rkvmss"
   },
   "instanceCount": {
     "value": 2
   },
   "adminUsername": {
     "value": "rajkumarun"
   },
   "adminPassword": {
     "reference": {
       "keyVault": {
         "id": "/subscriptions/*****-***-*****/resourceGroups/********-Mindtree/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/Rktestkeyvault1"
       },
       "secretName": "rksecretkv"
     }
   }
 }
```

[image]